# React useState with Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

So I have 3 Inputs, I want to get their state when updating onChange Input Attribute, the state that I want to get should look like this: `[{lang: (inputName), text: (inputValue)}, ..]`.

What I tried:

```
function onChange = (name, value) => {
  setState(prevState => [...prevState, {lang: name, text: value} ])
}
```

I think the solution would be filtering the `prevState`, since there are only 3 inputs, I could filter the array based on the `name` key. And show only the objects with genuine keys (not-repeated ones).

Comment: You want to "get" or "update"? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, it's React (2 way binding), so I want to both get the state and update it like it's shown.

Comment: React does not use two way data binding.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question but what I think you're asking is how to update the 'text' value of an object inside the array?

If so, you could do something like this:

```
function onChange = (name, value) => {
  setState(prevState => {
    let stateCopy = [...prevState];
    const index = stateCopy.findIndex(obj => obj.lang === name);
    stateCopy[index] = {...stateCopy[index], text: value};
    return stateCopy;
  }
}
```

Comment: This mutates state by directly updating a property on `prevState`'s nested object. It will most likely not cause any visible bugs right away since you're spreading `prevState` into a new array for the return, but it breaks the rules of React state, and could lead to future bugs.

Comment: @BrianThompson, yes, good point, I've updated the answer to make the new copy first and then update that.

Comment: Unfortunately the update still has the same problem. The nested object still points to the original reference in state. You would need to create a new nested object as well: `stateCopy[index] = {...stateCopy[index], text: value};`. Note that spreading objects/arrays into new ones only breaks the reference to the root. Nested references will remain untouched.

Comment: I hadn't considered that it was only a shallow copy, that's worth knowing, thank you